# how to expire recaptcha in node js after validation first time

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, recaptcha

I am using google recaptcha .when I checkbox of google .it generate a ** **`long string`****.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-recaptcha

I verify my long string on the backend node js.but it always gives **true**
when verifying with same string
I want it will give **true first time** other time it will give false other time with the same string.

here is my backend code

```
let {UserId,recaptchaString} = req.body;
        console.log(recaptchaString);


        if(recaptchaString ==null || recaptchaString === undefined || recaptchaString ===''){
            return  res.send({status: false,"message":"please select captcha"});

        } 

        var secertKey = ']sj2KiaboL6hJ9eIaiv6wRVbr';
        const verifyUrl = `https://google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${secertKey}&response=${recaptchaString}&remoteip=${req.connection.remoteAddress}`;
        request(verifyUrl, async (err, response, body) => {
            body = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(body);

            // If Not Successful
            if (body.success !== undefined && !body.success) {
                return res.json({"success": false, "msg": "Failed captcha verification"});
            }
         });
```

I am referring this video also
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UzCkSzmEq8E

Comment: Please remove your `secretKey` if that is your actual secret key and if it is, regenerate it for your application.

Comment: it is a fake key

Comment: What is `body.success !== undefined` supposed to do?

Comment: if is not success